# Using websockets and backbone to update the content of a webpage

Tags: backbone.js, websocket, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to use web sockets to update the content of a web page?

What I am trying to achieve is create a dynamic sign-up list. So using backbone and an mvc web API, I get json from the server by querying a database, then I apply this json to a template.

When someone new signs up, I want this to trigger an update for all clients connected to the server, sending a json representation of the new sign-up-ee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're using on the server side, but essentially you want to override `backbone.sync` which uses `$.ajax` by default to use the socket framework of your choice.

Here are a couple of articles that may help:

[SignalR](http://srtsolutions.github.com/backbone.signalr/)

[Socket IO](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/jasonstrimpel/2011/11/backbone-js-and-socket-io)

Hope this helps (p.s. we did this and it results in a seriously sexy app).  Good Luck

Comment: SignalR seems so cool. Is this what you used in your project. You used .Net? Do you have the project available on github?

Comment: No, sorry it was an internal, corporate app so no github for us

Comment: Ha no worries. Just one last question. Was it a .net 4.0 or 4.5 framework app.

Comment: Also see [backbone.js with Pusher](http://blog.pusher.com/2011/6/21/backbone-js-now-realtime-with-pusher) and [backbone live](https://github.com/bluedevil2k/backbone-live).